# Cache external static scripts?

Tags: cache, performance, page-speed

In my never ending quest for a faster website, I thought perhaps I could cache some scripts.  I'm using Yslow to rate my site, everything is pretty much A (which is great, our website on Pingdom loads in 0.4-0.6 seconds which is 5-20x quicker than our competitors) except two things:

Add expire headers:

```
(2011/7/7) http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?...
(2011/7/6) http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?...
(no expires) http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4d7a205f1e2a0b4b
```

And too many DNS lookups:

> The components are split over more
>   than 4 domains
>
> static1.scirra.net: 4 components,
>   19.3K (4.3K GZip)
>
> fonts.googleapis.com: 2 components,
>   0.8K (0.5K GZip)
>
> static3.scirra.net: 2 components, 5.5K
>   (2.7K GZip)
>
> static4.scirra.net: 3 components,
>   12.7K
>
> static2.scirra.net: 3 components,
>   76.6K
>
> s7.addthis.com: 3 components, 126.3K
>   (40.4K GZip)
>
> ajax.googleapis.com: 1 component,
>   78.6K (27.1K GZip)
>
> www.scirra.com: 1 component, 8.0K
>   (3.3K GZip)

This answer on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439042/how-can-i-add-expire-headers-for-scripts-that-are-not-on-my-server/1439128#1439128

Suggests having an intermediatory caching script, which fetches these and serves them from your own server.

Thoughts?  If you're a speed nut like me can we expect to shave some loading time off for the users at the expense of our bandwidth?

Comment: Note: there is a tradeoff if you cache them locally on your server... as you increase the load on your own server for those files when un-cached, and reduce the pipelining abilities of the browser by moving the scripts from a CDN http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn back onto your local server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moving *unique* static files to your own domain to reduce domain lookups and control expire headers is a good idea, provided you're prepared to check the master files for changes periodically.

Moving *common* static files to your own domain is not always a good idea, because you lose the benefit if they're already cached from another site the user may have visited. (e.g. Google Web Fonts and the JavaScript files hosted within the [Google Libraries API.](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/))

[Aside: To my knowledge, pingdom measures server *response* time, not page load time, but 0.6 seconds still sounds fast!]

Answer (score 4):

Bandwidth is almost a commodity at this point. Especially if you're [compressing your file](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4516/should-i-use-gzip)s before sending them to the user. And since page speed has been proven to affect not only [search rankings](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) but, more importantly, [conversion rates](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/web_performance_optimization_is_the_new_seo.html), I would say this is not a bad strategy to employ. Just make sure your caching engine accounts for updates to any of the external scripts you are caching. Being out of sync with them may cause undesirable results.